# How can I trigger Js function from template class in Odoo

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-16

```
        <template id="patient_summery" name="patient_id.summery">
            <header class="site-header" js_class="banner_summary_route">
                <div class="site-identity">
                    <h1><t t-esc="patient_id.name" />
                        <a href="#" class="editPatientProfile">
                            <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"
                               style="font-size:24px;color: white;"></i>
                        </a>
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </header>
        </template>
```

I want to trigger a js function in odoo when I click the class editPatientProfile like using event trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look to the standard modules in Odoo-16, for instance:  a rpc-call is used in this module: /addons/website_profile :

**THE VIEW**:

/addons/website_profile/views/website_profile.xml which contains `class="send_validation_email"` and `class="validated_email_close"`, having both click-events defined in the js file (see below).

```xml
<template id="user_profile_content" name="Profile Page Content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- ========== SIDEBAR ========== -->
                    ...
                <!-- ========== PROFILE CONTENT ========== -->
                    ...
                    <div class="tab-content py-4 o_wprofile_tabs_content mb-4" id="profile_extra_info_tabcontent">
                        <div role="tabpanel" t-attf-class="tab-pane #{ 'show active' if not active_tab or active_tab == 'about' else '' }" id="profile_tab_content_about">
                            <div class="o_wprofile_email_validation_container mb16 mt16">
                                <t t-call="website_profile.email_validation_banner">
                                    <t t-set="redirect_url" t-value="'/profile/user/%s' % user.id"/>
                                    <t t-set="additional_validation_email_message"/>
                                </t>
                            </div>
                            <div id="profile_about_badge" class="mb32">
                                <h5 class="border-bottom pb-1">Badges</h5>
                                <t t-call="website_profile.user_badges"></t>
                            </div>
                           ...
    </template>
    <template id="email_validation_banner">
        ...
        <div t-elif="not validation_email_sent and not is_public_user and user.karma == 0" t-att-class="send_alert_classes" role="alert">
            <button type="button" class="btn-close validation_email_close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"/>
            Your Account has not yet been verified.<br/>
            Click <a class="send_validation_email alert-link" href="#" t-att-data-redirect_url="redirect_url"><u>here</u></a> to receive a verification email<t t-esc="additional_validation_email_message"/>!
        </div>
        ...
     <div t-if="validation_email_done" t-att-class="done_alert_classes" role="status">
            <button type="button" class="btn-close validated_email_close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"/>
            <span id="email_validated_message">Congratulations! Your email has just been validated.</span>
            <span t-esc="additional_validated_email_message"/>
        </div>

</template>
```

**THE JS**:

The clicks events for the `<div class="send_validation_email">` and `<div class="validated_email_close">` are set here: /addons/website_profile/static/src/js/website_profile.js:

```js
odoo.define('website_profile.website_profile', function (require) {
'use strict';

var publicWidget = require('web.public.widget');
var wysiwygLoader = require('web_editor.loader');

publicWidget.registry.websiteProfile = publicWidget.Widget.extend({
    selector: '.o_wprofile_email_validation_container',
    read_events: {
        'click .send_validation_email': '_onSendValidationEmailClick',
        'click .validated_email_close': '_onCloseValidatedEmailClick',
    },


    // Handlers..
    _onSendValidationEmailClick: function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var $element = $(ev.currentTarget);
        this._rpc({
            route: '/profile/send_validation_email',
            params: {'redirect_url': $element.data('redirect_url')},
        }).then(function (data) {
            if (data) {
                window.location = $element.data('redirect_url');
            }
        });
    },

    _onCloseValidatedEmailClick: function () {
        this._rpc({
            route: '/profile/validate_email/close',
        });
    },
});
```

**THE MANIFEST**:

In `/addons/website_profile/__manifest__.py` file, the corresponding lines:

```py
    'data': [
        #...
        'views/website_profile.xml',
        #...
    ],
     'assets': {
        'web.assets_frontend': [
            'website_profile/static/src/scss/website_profile.scss',
            'website_profile/static/src/js/website_profile.js',
        ],
    },
```

Comment: RPC and so many other things are not avilable because this way not extending any abstract action or somehting like that.

Comment: I actually want to open form view using rpc

Comment: Could you provide the draft of your js code please ?

Comment: would you give me your email?

Comment: I can send you the template js file and the way  am trying to do it.

Comment: you can just post it here in your Question

Comment: ok i have just changed the content of my answer to provide you a full example. You just have to follow this structure to manage your own process. Good luck !